# How to test my own image on a MNIST trained network?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, mnist

This is my first time trying to train a network and use PyTorch, so please forgive me if this is considered simple.

I have a pretrained AlexNet network that was modified to classify 3 classes, which I've already trained on MNIST that I mapped to 3 different labels.

```
class Net( nn.Module ) :
    def __init__( self ) :
        super( Net, self ).__init__()
        
        self.model = models.alexnet( pretrained = True )
        # changed in_channels from 3 to 1 bc images are black and white 
        self.model.features[ 0 ] = nn.Conv2d( 1, 64, kernel_size = 11, stride = 4, padding = 2 )
        
        # binary classifier -> 3 out_features
        self.model.classifier[ 4 ] = nn.Linear( 4096, 1024 )
        self.model.classifier[ 6 ] = nn.Linear( 1024, 3 )
        
    def forward( self, x ):
        return self.model( x )
    
model = Net().to( device )
```

I want to test this on a single .png image that I drew, which is already 255x255, and in black and white. I would like the predicted label. This is the code I have so far for preprocessing the image:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
image_8 = Image.open( "eight.png" ).convert('L')

image_8 = list( image_8.getdata())
normalized_8 = [(255 - x) * 1.0 / 255.0 for x in image_8 ]
tensor_8 = torch.FloatTensor( normalized_8 )

pred = model( tensor_8 )
```

from which I got the following error: `Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 1, 11, 11], but got 1-dimensional input of size [50176] instead`. So this is clearly the wrong way to do things, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your inference code to the following. Images are not intended to be flattened into 1d.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
image_8 = cv2.imread("eight.png")

# following line may or may not be necessary
image_8 = cv2.cvtColor(image_8, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# you can divide numpy arrays by a constant natively
image_8 /= 255.

# This makes a 4d tensor (batched image) with shape [1, channels, width, height]
image_8 = torch.Tensor(tensor_8).unsqueeze(axis=0)

pred = model(image_8)
```

If the image is still 3d (shape of `[1, width, height]`), add a second `.unsqueeze(axis=0)`.

Comment: I changed my code to follow your suggestion, and now I'm getting this error instead: "Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 1, 11, 11], but got 3-dimensional input of size [1, 224, 224] instead" :(

Comment: Are you sure you're adding the `unsqueeze(axis=0)`? If you are, you may have to unsqueeze it again for the fourth "batch" dimension.

Comment: I added a second unsqueeze, and that fixed everything - thank you :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help! If you would like to help me out, I would highly appreciate if you could mark my answer as solved and upvote it. Thanks!